# stop Callable task in ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, future

I'm learning concurrency and made some naive program to play with `ExecutorService` and `Future` tasks.

Also I want to check why `instanceof` is bad in some cases.

```
public class Test {

static enum Some {
    FOO;
}

static abstract class Foo {
    public abstract Some getType();
}

static class FooExt extends Foo {
    public Some getType() {
        return Some.FOO;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Future<Integer> f1 = service.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() {
            try {
                start.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Task started...");
            int a = 0;
            Foo foo = new FooExt();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (foo instanceof FooExt) {
                    a++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Task ended...");
            return a;
        }
    });

    Future<Integer> f2 = service.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() {
            try {
                start.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Task started...");
            int a = 0;
            Foo foo = new FooExt();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (foo.getType() == Some.FOO) {
                    a++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Task ended...");
            return a;
        }
    });
    start.countDown();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    service.shutdownNow();
    System.out.println("service is shutdowned...");
    try {
        System.out.println("instanceof: "+f1.get());
        System.out.println("enum: "+f2.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

but unfortunately my code is never terminated, and I cant get any values from my tasks :(

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/AYmuZD
Please compare the imports with the code posted in previous link. Tried with ideone and also locally with Java 6, nothing surprising in there.

Comment: I've tried it many times, but only what I see is: Task started...
Task started...
service is shutdowned...

Comment: You might want to look into `jstack`, which lets you the stack traces for all threads in your JVM. It's always a good first step for figuring out what's going on in a "stuck" Java app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have executed your program. I got the following output:

```
Task started...
Task started...
Task ended...
service is shutdowned...
Task ended...
instanceof: 1287184
enum: 1247375
```

This code terminates.

Comment: Work perfect at home too, but does not work at my "work" PC... Can't figure out